# How to detect two different mice at the same time, and record their separate movements?

Tags: input, windows, mouse

I would like to use two computer mice simultaneously, and to record data their separate movements on windows. I have successfully used TeamPlayer to create two cursors, but the software that I am using to record the movement data records only one output - the sum of the two cursors. How am I to use both computer mice at once, and record their separate outputs?

I have looked at the thread [Is it possible to detect two different mice at the same time, and have their movements recorded seperately?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24046/is-it-possible-to-detect-two-different-mice-at-the-same-time-and-have-their-mov), but this is quite old now and most of the solutions offered are now unavailable.

Comment: What specifically did you try from that thread, and what prevented it from working?

Comment: I understand that the other question is old and dusty; I have cleaned it up a bit. Your question is still a duplicate but having asked it will likely attract attention to the other one.

Comment: I have added a comment to that other question, maybe you could try to explore that.